# Joining SendLog and Click Data View does not return any results

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, query, dataextensions, data-views

I want pull out the list of customers that did not click on the mail we sent.

We maintain a SendLog in which we have additional attributes logged (Example: emailname, subject etc.)

I understand  that we can use Sent data view. But I wish to use SendLog instead as it has additional fields.

Here is the query I have used to join SendLog & Clicks. But the results is null.
Please could anyone help me fix this problem

```
select  se.EmailAddress,se.TimeStamp as sentdate
from SendLog se
inner join [_click]  cl
on  se.JobID=cl.JobID and se.BatchID=cl.BatchID and se.SubID=cl.SubscriberID
where se.EmailName_ = 'hello'  and cl.SubscriberID is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you are doing an INNER JOIN, which requires the record to exist in BOTH tables (DEs) in order to be returned. The OPs code is basically saying return all records that match on both tables but are empty on the second one. Since it cannot exist but also not exist, it returns 0.

As you are looking for records that are both in and NOT in the _Click DV, this is causing you to return 0 results.

What you want to do is instead utilize a LEFT JOIN (pulls all results from initial table (de) and any that match in second (de).

By then pulling only records that have a click subID of null, it will remove any matches and will instead only pull those in the send log that are not in click.

Like this:

```sql
select  se.EmailAddress
,se.TimeStamp as sentdate
from SendLog se
left join [_click]  cl
on  se.JobID=cl.JobID and se.BatchID=cl.BatchID and se.SubID=cl.SubscriberID
where se.EmailName_ = 'hello'  and cl.SubscriberID is null
```

Another option too is to instead utilize `NOT EXISTS` instead of a left join.

Something like:

```sql
select  se.EmailAddress
,se.TimeStamp as sentdate
from SendLog se
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT TOP 1 cl.SubscriberID FROM [_click]  cl
  WHERE se.JobID=cl.JobID and se.BatchID=cl.BatchID and se.SubID=cl.SubscriberID
)
AND se.EmailName_ = 'hello'
```

They will likely process and function the same, so its more a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SFSE!

Please review `_Click` Data View [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5), where it is shown that the `SubscriberID` field is not nullable, thus you cannot have `WHERE` clause with `cl.SubscriberID is null` and `INNER JOIN` at the same time, which makes you have 0 records in the result.

You should either adjust conditions in the `WHERE` clause or select another type of `JOIN`, depending on what would suit your needs better.

Comment: This is incorrect. The click subID can be nullable as its a join tothe sendlog. Where an email can be sent but not clicked. so click subID would be null.  The issue is the INNER JOIN.

Comment: It can be nullable when you use other join types but the field itself is non-nullable and that is a fact. that is what I said in my answer that OP should either adjust WHERE clause conditions or change INNER JOIN to something else but that is his business how to proceed.

Comment: Whether the field is nullable or not in the DV makes no difference in his issue though. And the statement `thus you cannot have WHERE clause with cl.SubscriberID is null, which makes you have 0 records in the result.` is 100% incorrect. You can have this statement on a join. It is basically using a left join as an exclusion.

Comment: I was referring to the OP's SQL where we have INNER JOIN. There is no point to discuss what is generally possible or not, since there are millions of different approaches but each one of them would suit a different purpose.

Comment: With the update your answer is no longer incorrect. Thank you for updating it. And discussing possible or not IS the whole point of forums like these. There are a million different solutions in a million different ways. But this was about an incorrect statement, not possibilities.